# SolrNet PostSolrConnection decorator using Windsor Container sends Bad Request

Tags: post, solrnet

We implement Solr search in a document manager we use. When a user requests to search for all the documents in a given directory, we are forced to aggregate the `docid`s of the user's selected documents into an array and send a

```
SolrQueryInList("docid", arrFileNames)
```

If the number of files in the user's directory is very large, so is the resulting http request. **Ergo**, we decided to use SolrPostConnection. In our site we implement the PostSolrConnection decorator within the Windsor container, as per [M. Scheeffer's instructions](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/12/customizing-solrnet.html):

```
public SolrSearchRepository(int caseID, string solrServer)           
{           
    this.facility = new SolrNetFacility(solrServer);
    this.facility.AddCore(caseID.ToString(), typeof(SolrDocument), 
        string.Format("{0}/{1}", solrServer, caseID));
    this.container = new WindsorContainer();
    this.container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>()
             .ImplementedBy<PostSolrConnection>()
             .DependsOn(Parameter.ForKey("serverUrl").Eq(solrServer)));
    this.container.AddFacility(this.facility);
    solrOperation = this.container
             .Resolve<ISolrOperations<SolrDocument>>(caseID.ToString()); 
}
```

**However**, we are still getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an
error: (400) Bad Request.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at
HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()\r\n   at
SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)\r\n   at
SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)"}
```

We use Tomcat 7.0 server. The logs are pretty uniformative. Here's the pastebin of what seems to happen around the time I launch a search:

### [Solr Log](http://pastebin.com/zvFmnK3A)

I noticed that the command never reaches the server. Is the PostSolrConnection not implementing `post`? Note that this query works perfectly with small number of files (i.e. `docid`'s)

Comment: You need more information from logs. Crank up the logging levels to the max. Otherwise it's all just guessing.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Please see the edit. I hung a much longer log record on pastebin.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I don't know enough about Solr logging to recognize whether it logged a search query. To my inexperienced eyes it looks like nothing is logging on the server, primarily because the query never reaches it. What do you think? Is there a way to peek inside the Windsor container and see what's being implemented? **Note**: As a last ditch effort, I re-wrote the `PostSolarConnection` implementation you posted (as `PostSolarConnection2`) and registered my local copy with Windsor. No change.

Comment: You need more logging from Tomcat to confirm GET or POST. Or use something like Fiddler.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Suppose it never gets to Tomcat...

Comment: That "bad request" error comes from Solr/Tomcat, so yes, something is getting to Tomcat.